# Unable to create Career.Stackoverflow profile

Tags: support, jobs

I have requested a invitation for Careers.Stackoverflow.com and I did receive one but when I used it (within the 14 day period) it says that "it has been used already or has expired". I was login to StackExchange using another account and I might have been screw up while applying that invitation.

And when I try to request another invitation it says "An invitation request has already been made for this email address".

Could someone help?

Comment: You might get better and faster response by emailing directly to careers@stackoverflow.com